# django.core.context_processors.request not being added

Tags: django, request

This is defined in my settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR = (
     "django.core.context_processors.request", # <- HERE
     "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
     "django.core.context_processors.debug",
     "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
     "django.core.context_processors.media",
     "django.core.context_processors.static",
     "django.core.context_processors.tz",
     "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)
```

And this is in my view file:

```
def home(request):
     ctx = {}
     request.session['test'] = 1
     return render(request, 'home.html', ctx)
     # return render_to_response('home.html', ctx, 
     #                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If I try to access the request object from the template (for example `{{ request.session.test }}`, nothing is shown. Django debug toolbar shows that in the CONTEXT_PREPROCESSOR `django.core.context_processors.request` is not added. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing an 's'. You should define `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings file.